# Keeping list inline with text while keeping list vertically positioned

Tags: html, css

Right now this displays as: text 1 2 3 4 with the list appearing horizontally inline with the text. Is there a way to make the list display vertically while still remaining inline with the text?  (instead of text 1 2 3 4, the 2 should appear below the 1, 3 below the two, etc. but the list will still appear to the right of "text" and in the same line as "text")

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

HTML

```
<div id = "text">text</div>
<ul id="ulist">
   <li id="contents">1</li>
   <li id="contents">2</li>
   <li id="contents">3</li>
   <li id="contents">4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#ulist {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#contents {
    display: inline-block;
}

#text {
    display: inline;
}

#text2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Like this..? http://jsfiddle.net/cknfb/

Comment: Similar. But with "text" still on line 1 (next to 1 instead of 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, get rid of your rules and just float the div to the left:

```
#text {
    float:left;
}
```

Note that IDs **must** be unique.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7HAAe/)**

Comment: Phenomenal! Having unique IDs did the trick! Just wondering..why must all the contents of the list have a unique ID?

Comment: @user2888188 IDs are suppose to be unique by design, use classes for things that are repeated.

Comment: Ah yes, rookie mistake. But i shouldn't even need any ids or classes in this case. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: @JoshC the problem now is centering the text after floating it left. the list gets centered, but the text remains stubborn

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block;` to your `li` elements, modify #text to `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align: top`, and that should cause them to stack.

```
#ulist {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#ulist li {
    display: block;
}

#contents {
    display: inline-block;
}

#text {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#text2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I think this ends up like http://jsfiddle.net/cknfb/ where "text" is no longer on line 1.

Comment: @user2888188 - you are right.  Made adjustments to the answer that cause it to work correctly.

Comment: I was able to achieve the answer using float left on the text. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2888188 - good, I'm glad.  Keep in mind that float has other consequences that you may not want, but may be the right thing for you in this case.

Comment: I see what you were saying. I am having trouble center the text after floating it. I tried using your method and bring the text up to line with the first item in the list but haven't been successful ...tried padding, height adjustments, etc.

Comment: @alexj - make sure you notice the `vertical-align:top` on the `#text` element.  That will bring it up to the top.