# Using JS to cycle list while keeping in line with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Related to my question seen here: [Keeping list inline with text while keeping list vertically positioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440851/keeping-list-inline-with-text-while-keeping-list-vertically-positioned)

Having trouble cycling through a list using js while keeping the list in-line with some text. Floating the text left solves the problem, until i have to format and center the text/list.

what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/pthbK/
trying to achieve something similar to: https://www.youeye.com/

The list appends up for some reason, causing the text to appear slightly below the list. Goal is to get list appearing directly beside the list (to the left in my case).

```
<center>
<div id = "text">Sometext&nbsp;</div>
    <ul id = "ticker">
        <li>3</li>   
        <li>2</li>
        <li>1</li>
   </ul>





#ticker {
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: oustide;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
}
#ticker li {
    height: 40px;
}
#text {
    display: inline;
}



function tick(){
$('#ticker li:first').animate({'opacity':0}, 200, function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).css('opacity', 1); });
}
setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="center">You ate an <span id="text"></span>.</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var i = 0,
    texts = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];

function cycleText() {
    $("#text").text(texts[i]);
    if ((i += 1) === texts.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
cycleText();
setInterval(cycleText, 1000);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aeoril/NfUUC/)